# XML and probably LXML issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

I have many XML files that look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<reiXmlPrenos>
  <Qfl>1808</Qfl>
  <fOVE>13.7</fOVE>
  <NetoVolumen>613</NetoVolumen>
  <Hv>104.2</Hv>
  <energenti>
    <energent>
      <sifra>energy_e</sifra>
      <naziv>EE [kWh]</naziv>
      <vrednost>238981</vrednost>
    </energent>
    <energent>
      <sifra>energy_to</sifra>
      <naziv>Do</naziv>
      <vrednost>16359</vrednost>
    </energent>
    <energent>
      <sifra>energy_en</sifra>
      <naziv>En</naziv>
      <vrednost>0</vrednost>
    </energent>
</energenti>
  <rei>
    <zavetrovanost>2</zavetrovanost>
    <cone>
      <cona>
        <cona_id>1</cona_id>
        <cc_si_cona>1110000</cc_si_cona>
        <visina_cone>2.7</visina_cone>
        <dolzina_cone>14</dolzina_cone>
      </cona>
      <cona>
        <cona_id>2</cona_id>
        <cc_si_cona>120000</cc_si_cona>
      </cona>
  </rei>
</reiXmlPrenos>
```

I would like to extract certain values from those XML files. So I put together with the help from people here code below that is suppose to work:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
from lxml import etree


os.chdir(r'R:\...\XML-1122_test')
dir_path = glob.glob('*.xml')
xmls = dir_path


#note: For simplicity, I'm using the well formed version of the xml strings in your question; you'll have to use actual file names and paths
energies = ["xml", "energy_ge", "energy_en", "energy_dteu", "energy_dtlb"]
#I just made up some names - you'll have to use actual names, of course; the first one is for the file identifier - see below
rows = []
for xml in xmls:
    row = []
    id = "xml-"+str(xmls.index(xml)+1)
    #this creates the file identifier
    row.append(id)
    root = etree.XML(xml.encode())
    #in real life, you'll have to use the parse() method
    
    for energy in energies[1:]:
        #the '[1:]' is used to skip the first "energy"; it's only used as the file identifier
        target = root.xpath(f'//energent[./sifra[.="{energy}"]]/vrednost/text()')
        #note the use of f-strings
        row.extend( target if len(target)>0 else "0" )
    rows.append(row)

print(pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=energies))
```

But in the end I get a warning:

```
File "<string>", line 1
XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

Is this an XML issue? Or maybe lxml issue? Does anyone know how to approach this?

Ideally, the result would look like this

```
xml       energy_e   energy_en   energy_to
xml-1    238981      0         16539 
xml-2    ...         ..        ..
```

Comment: The space is result from my copy-paste process. XML files don't have the space at the very beginning. And all the other tags are present as well, i copied only a fraction of the files just to give you and idea how it looks like.

Comment: @energyMax, can you add the exact expected dataframe (*matching your input*) ?

Comment: Are you using `etree.XML(xml.encode())` intead of parse? `xmls` are filepaths not xml content

Comment: The entire code is presented above.

Comment: That might be the problem then. You should use `parse()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
from lxml import etree


os.chdir(r'R:\...\XML-1122_test')
dir_path = glob.glob('*.xml')
xmls = dir_path

energies = ["xml", "energy_e", "energy_en", "energy_to"]
rows = []
for xml in xmls:
    row = []
    id = "xml-"+str(xmls.index(xml)+1)
    row.append(id)
    with open(xml, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        xml_string = f.read()
    root = etree.XML(xml_string.encode())
    
    for energy in energies[1:]:
        target = root.xpath(f'//energent[./sifra="{energy}"]/vrednost/text()')
        row.extend(target if len(target)>0 else ["0"])
    rows.append(row)

print(pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=energies)
```

parse below

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
from lxml import etree


os.chdir(r'R:\...\XML-1122_test')
dir_path = glob.glob('*.xml')
xmls = dir_path


energies = ["xml", "energy_ge", "energy_en", "energy_dteu", "energy_dtlb"]
rows = []
for xml in xmls:
    row = []
    id = "xml-"+str(xmls.index(xml)+1)
    row.append(id)
    root = etree.parse(xml)
    
    for energy in energies[1:]:
        target = root.xpath(f'//energent[./sifra[.="{energy}"]]/vrednost/text()')
        row.extend( target if len(target)>0 else "0" )
    rows.append(row)

print(pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=energies))
```

Comment: Does this fix your problem?

Comment: Not yet. Does it play any role that at first there is `energenti` and only after that `energent`. So `energenti` is above them all... I get the same warning even now

Comment: I have edited the post to better fix your problem and answer your new question. Please tell me if this fixes your problem.

Comment: Can you please give the entire code as a hole? I'm a bit confused on some parts atm

Comment: Ok, please give me one minute to collect it

Comment: I can also do it by using parse as that is a viable solution.

Comment: ok here is both of the code

Answer (score 4):

Since you're looking for a *dataframe*, you can simply use [`read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
df = (
    pd.read_xml(xml, xpath=".//energent")
        .drop("naziv", axis=1)
        .set_index("sifra").T
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

And this is how you can incorporate it in your code :

```
xmls = glob.glob("*.xml")

list_dfs = []
for idx, xml in enumerate(xmls, start=1):
    tmp_df = (
        pd.read_xml(xml, xpath=".//energent")
            .drop("naziv", axis=1)
            .set_index("sifra").T
            .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    )
    tmp_df.insert(0, "xml", f"{xml}-{idx}")
    list_dfs.append(tmp_df)
    
df = pd.concat(list_dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

​
Test/Output (*x3 the same xml*):

```
print(df) 

            xml  energy_e  energy_to  energy_en
0   first.xml-1    238981      16359          0
1  second.xml-2    238981      16359          0
2   third.xml-3    238981      16359          0
```

Comment: Can you please put the entire code? I am (obviously) not very good in python, so i can't understand all the logic atm

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check it out ?

Comment: `NameError: name 'StringIO' is not defined` is the error

Comment: That's because I used `io` to read the xml, I corrected the code.